# Why is my SelectList populating with an unwanted blank option selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working to create a view that contains a dropdownlist.  To generate the select list items, I wrote a method to return the list of `SelectListItem` desired for this dropdown - one of which has an attribute of Selected  set to true.

I have traced through the method generating the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` representative of the options I wish to render, and it is returning the desired result.

However when I use `Html.DropDownList()` utilizing the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` returned above, my rendered select element
has an initial blank option which does not appear in the DOM.  Selecting any option will remove it, but I am confused as to why
the selected option from the `List<SelectListItem>` is not honored.

Static method generating list of `SelectListItem`:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDropDownValues()
{
    IEnumerable<MyClass> myClassesForList = MyClass.GetItemsForList();
    List<SelectListItem> retVal = new List<SelectListItem>();
    retVal.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Choose", Value = "0", Selected=true });

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> myClassesSelectListItems =
        from x in myClassesForList
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.Name,
            Value = x.Value
        };

    return retVal.Concat(myClassesSelectListItems);
}
```

Pertinent Razor snippet:

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropDownVals", GetDropDownValues())
```

***Edit 1***: Screenshot of resulting drop-down list

[image: Screenshot of resulting DropDownList]

Comment: Are you sure there's not a viewbag/viewdata named dropDownVals which holds a value that doesn't exist in the list returned by GetDropDownValues()?

Comment: why don't you use `.Concat` for both operations instead of `.Add` & `.Concat`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's not a viewbag/viewdata named `dropDownVals`, which holds a value that doesn't exist in the list returned by the method `GetDropDownValues`

What if you use `AddRange` instead of `Concat`:

```
retVal.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Choose", Value = "0", Selected=true });
var myClassesSelectListItems = from x in myClassesForList
                               select new SelectListItem
                               {
                                   Text = x.Name,
                                   Value = x.Value
                               };

retVal.AddRange(myClassesSelectListItems);

return retVal;
```

Comment: You will also need to add  `retVal.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Choose", Value = "0",Selected=true });` since this is the `Selected` value that he is originally looking for in his question